# ошибка в утверждении static_assert

Tags: c++

В чем причина ошибки:

> Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error
>   (active)  E0028   expression must have a constant value?

в функции

```
void
foo(const size_t a, const size_t b)
{   
    static_assert(a >= b);
    //...
}
```

Comment: static_assert работает во время компиляции.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Проверка static_assert, в отличии от assert, проверяется во время компиляции, а не вовремя выполнения. Т.е. значения а и b должны быть константами времени компиляции, но компилятор не знает с ками аргументами вы вызовете функцию.

Модификатор const (в отличии от constexpr), означает что функция не будет изменять параметры переданные ей с этим модификатором, но аргументы вызова функции не обязаны быть константами.

Замените на  assert, ли укажите параметры не аргументами функции, а аргументами шаблона функции:

```
template<size_t a, size_t b>
void
foo()
{   
    static_assert(a >= b);
    //...
}

foo<1,2>();
```